# Making .on() handler react only to element's own event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Is there a more elegant way to avoid reacting to bubbling events from descendants than this:

```
$('#element').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target != this)
        return;
    alert("it's a-me!");
});
```

([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpuga/1/)).

Maybe some parameter to `.on()` or some other method I'm missing?

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` ?

Comment: No, that's pretty much the most elegant way to handle it. The only other way requires you to bind events on child elements and for the child elements to know that they need to stop propagation to prevent a click event on a possibly non-related element.

Comment: I see. I'd hoped jQuery had some sugar for that. I don't really want to stop propagation, just ignore the event in a specific handler as it continues bubbling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's pretty much the most elegant way to handle it.

The only other way requires you to bind events on child elements and stoppropagation there, however, that would mean the child elements need to know about the parent element that may or may not be related. Better to just keep it within the single event, it will have the least impact on the rest of the page/application.

Another reason why that is the best way to handle it is it won't break any events that are being delegated to said child elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think return it not enough.
Look in https://myprettycms.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#461106
Method:

```
$.fn.ensureStopPropagation = function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

Comment: he's trying to stop a child event, not this event. the return in his code simply exits the event without preventing anything.